# Python 3 threading.enumerate() exception

Tags: django, multithreading, python-3.x, exception, enums

I'm writing django based web, where my application is running. User gives passes some parameters and the application is started in its own thread. For debugging purposes I want to print to console all active threads. I use python threading module and following code:

```
import threading

def some_func():
    print(threading.enumerate())
    .
    .
    .
```

and this call leads to the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bakajsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mysite\my_project\views.py", line 90, in some_func
    print(threading.enumerate())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 824, in __repr__
    self.is_alive() # easy way to get ._is_stopped set when appropriate
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 1120, in is_alive
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock(False)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 1076, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    assert self._is_stopped
AssertionError
```

Do you have any idea what could possibly go wrong?

According to documentation:

threading.enumerate()

Return a list of all Thread objects currently alive. The list includes daemonic threads, dummy thread objects created by current_thread(), and the main thread. It excludes terminated threads and threads that have not yet been started.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the print problem

Try this:

`for thread in threading._enumerate():
    print(thread.name)`